# Vue. Отслеживание скролинга

Tags: прокрутка, vue.js

Здравствуйте, интересует такой вопрос, как отследить что я проскролил до одного блока, далее к второму, или как отследить что я сейчас смотрю на третий блок?

> http://gabegsell.com/anchors/ - например как тут, скролиш - получаеш
>   .push('#anchors2'), и т.д. ...

Как такое реализовать во Vue? Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел аналог для Vue.js : https://github.com/eddiemf/vue-scrollactive

Demo:  https://eddiemf.github.io/vue-scrollactive/examples/example-1.html