# Как отслеживать scroll?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как отследить scroll во vue? Вот смотрите, есть `div.header.uk-container` с высотой 50px, когда пользователь опуститься ниже чем на 100px к `div.header.uk-container` добавиться класс headerAfter, как такое сделать? Главное, покажите как отследить изменения scroll'a остальное сам, пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: на ваш вопрос есть ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720524/vue-%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение: к `div'у` добавляем такой атрибут `v-on:scroll="onScroll"`
Далее создаем метод onScroll

```
onScroll(event){
//делаем какие-то действия во время прокрутки
}
```

И еще создаем эти два хука:

```
created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
},
destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
},
```

Comment: ты что сам на свой вопрос ответил и добавил себе +50 репутации?

Comment: @LyubaIvanova Не)) Не добавил)  ну я отметил свой ответ решением, а они не вернулись)))

Comment: @Евгений Чтобы авторы не абузили.

Answer (score 1):

Мне больше нравится запись: @scroll="functionName" на любом блоке. Работает, как часы и выглядит в духе vue, без костыльных ивентов на window (вообще не понятно зачем ты их юзаешь).